# Blank Page while viewing Report in Lightning Community using customer community plus license?

Tags: lightning, community, reporting

We have created a portal based on Lightning Community (Napili) template.

We would like to allow users with "Customer Community Plus" license to access report using the following URL:

```
https://<host>/<community_name>/s/report/00Or0000000LX6s (report id).
```

Gave all the "Reports" related permissions to the profile.

Still, we are seeing blank page while accessing the above URL.

Why is this page blank? How can we fix it?